# Entity Framework Core error after migrating ASPNET MVC RC1 into RC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am migrating my app from ASPNET MVC RC1 into RC2 following the following video and post:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPf3D9CqRDk
- https://www.wildermuth.com/2016/05/17/Converting-an-ASP-NET-Core-RC1-Project-to-RC2

So far I managed to get my app to compile but it breaks on runtime showing the following error related to Entity Framework:

> An exception of type `'System.InvalidOperationException'` occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot remove key {`Id`} from entity type
>   `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUser`
>   because it is referenced by a foreign key in entity type
>   `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserClaim<string>`.
>   All foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the referenced
>   key can be removed.

Below is the code I am using in the context class:

```
public class AppContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity1> Entities1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entity2> Entities2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entity3> Entities3 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicantionUsers { get; set; }

    public AppContext(DbContextOptions<AppContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("the connection string...");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

The code breaks in the AppContext constructor (first line). I tried removing that line but it breaks in the next one. If I remove the DbSets the code passes through but the tables are not created.

I tried adding a public string Id property to the ApplicationUser class (despite it should inherit it from IdentityUser) but got the same error. Below is the code for the ApplicationUser class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace AppNamespace
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public enum Gender { Male, Female }

        public enum UserStatus { Inactive, Active }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Passport { get; set; }

        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
        public int ReferenceNumber { get; private set; }
        public int Referral { get; set; }
        public bool AcceptedTermsAndConditions { get; set; }

        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }

        public string AddressLine { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Gonzalo

Comment: dnx is gone in RC2. You need to use `dotnet`

Comment: Yes, that's true. I tried dnx because dotnet has no entity framework commands. My main issue is the "Cannot remove key {'Id'} from entity type", but I don't understand why that happens. I am using DbSet<Entity> in my context, maybe I need to change that..?

Comment: I will edit my question to add the context code and remove that about dnx, as I think it will help improve the description

Comment: Can you post the code for `ApplicationUser`? It is telling you that it is trying to remove the `Id` column of your implementation of `IdentityUser` (`ApplicationUser`) using automatic migrations but it can't because it's being used.

Comment: Done. I tried adding a public string Id property to the class (despite it should inherit it from IdentityUser) but got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue was that the context was not providing the ApplicationUser when deriving from IdentityDbContext.
This fixed the problem:

```
public class AppContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{ 
    ...
}
```